# underscore.js .map method breaks ie8

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, underscore.js

I use backbone.js, this code is works fine all modern browser except internet explorer.

```
var posts = postList.map(function(model){ return model.toJSON(); });
```

Something wrong with the toJSON() method, what can I do?

**Edit:**

```
var posts = postList.map(function(model){ return model });
```

without toJSON(), still not working, maybe the .map method is the guilty?

Comment: Is the data being returned via JSON to big? Try it with a reduced data size and see if the problem still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
var posts = _.map(postsList, function(model) { return model; });
```

Comment: The OP is using the native JS .map function on arrays. Calling _.map(ARRAY, [predicate]) uses underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The `toJSON` method was introduced in JavaScript 1.8.5.

You can use Douglas Crockford's polyfill script for browsers that don't have JavaScript 1.8.5.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

For me, on ie8, the answer turned out to be that _.map@1.7.0 was iterating over all properties in an object (is `postslist` a hash?) including the inherited Object.prototype.toString method. 
This caused posts to the server that looked like this:

```
{ a:1,b:2, /* ... */ toString:'function(){ [native code] }'}
```

With some extraneous linefeed-carriagereturn characters. The addition of which, caused the server to choke.